# Using annotate and distinct on query set

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Here I'm trying to get count of each position from `PunchRawData` after filtering out distinct related values.
for that I need following code to work together.

```
queryset = PunchRawData.objects.filter(punch_type=IN, actual_clock_datetime__date=actual_clock_datetime).distinct('employee')
trade_based = queryset.values('employee__position').annotate(emp_count=Count('employee__position'))
```

But I get this error:

```
NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Do you want to count the distinct related employees, which is why you use `distinct`?

Comment: I want count of each position of distinct related employees.

Answer (score 0):

Apply annotate first and then use distinct. Plus you can achieve this only using one query there is no need for another variable

```
queryset = PunchRawData.objects.filter(punch_type=IN, actual_clock_datetime__date=actual_clock_datetime).annotate(emp_count=Count('employee__position', distinct=True)).values('emp_count')
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: this doesn't work. This is a special condition which requires another method to work. Currently i'm researching to resolve this.

Comment: you can use distinct inside count. I have updated my answer.Hope it will work now.

Comment: this will not work too. I have tried using `distinct=True` before. This will not give expected results.